# Android blow detection

Tags: android

I want to make app like appy birthday, in which i can detect blow whenever user blows in mic, Currently i am using a code which is not efficient as it also detect the noise and normal sound, i am using Media Record class .
I have tried this approach for detecting blow

```
public boolean isBlowing()
    {
        boolean recorder=true;

        int minSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        AudioRecord ar = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,minSize);


        short[] buffer = new short[minSize];

        ar.startRecording();
        while(recorder)
        {

            ar.read(buffer, 0, minSize);
            for (short s : buffer) 
            {
                if (Math.abs(s) > 27000)   //DETECT VOLUME (IF I BLOW IN THE MIC)
                {
                    blow_value=Math.abs(s);
                    System.out.println("Blow Value="+blow_value);
                    ar.stop();
                    recorder=false;

                    return true;

                }

            }
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Guys if you have code that detect only blow not normal sound please provide,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem.You find the solution?